# Firebase Reauthenticate and Change Password

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

```
  const newPassword=verifyPassword
  if(verifyPassword===verifyconfirmPassword)
  {
  updatePassword(auth?.currentUser,newPassword).then(()=>{
    alert("Update successful")
  })
  }
```

I want to change password if i am logged into account already
example if i am logged into accound and i want to change password so how to approach that functionality

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? Is there an error message?

Comment: yes recent login required

Comment: That sounds like the sign-in is too old to be allowed to change the password, and you'll have to sign the user in again as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user